# How to manage three, five or any odd numbers of Elementor columns in tablet mode?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Basically, I create two rows with 5 columns in each to display the 10 cities.
[Please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZQlL.jpg).

I'm facing an issue with odd numbers of Elementor column layout in the tablet mode. I display 2 columns in a row in a tablet mode. But theare are 5 columns in a row so last column is place with blank space along side and next row is start with two coumns. [Display on teblet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq1IP.png).

It's looks so ugly in a tablet mode. So what is the possible solution for that?

Comment: Share the screenshot of control settings with the editor preview panel which you are using to create the table UI

Comment: Please check the screenshots https://prnt.sc/wglp6f

Comment: Click the layout icon present at the top left corner just above the goa beach image when you clicked the layout icon the settings panel rerender with layout settings so snap that and share the same